# open close animation in vertical to horizontal

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I have created 5 boxes with heading when hover on box, now there is animation, one box open in top second box open in bottom vertically, I need same boxes open in horizontally one box should open left second box should open in right, I am doing for mobile view. I have attached images for reference, please help...much appreciated

[image]

[image]

```css
.container-five-steps{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face{
    width: 235px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face1{
    position: relative;
    background: #009297;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(100px);
    height: 280px;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps:hover .face.face1{
    background: #009297;
    transform: translateY(0);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 99px #00000029;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face1 .content{
    /*opacity: 0.2;*/
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps:hover .face.face1 .content{
    opacity: 1;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face1 .content img{
    max-width: 50px;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face1 .content h4{
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:100;
}

.bg-color-five-step h3{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight:500;
}


.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face2{
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px rgb(17 125 128);
    transform: translateY(-180px);
    height: 280px;
}
.five-step-icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: -6%;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps:hover .face.face2{
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face2 .content p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #009297;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face2 .content a{
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    display:  inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFDB72;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 9px;
}

.container-five-steps .card-five-steps .face.face2 .content a:hover{
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-five-steps">
        <div class="card-five-steps">       
            <img src="images/vector/icon_5 step.png" width="30" height="30" class="five-step-icon">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="images/1.png">
                    <h4>Heading <br>Sub Heading</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                <p class="fw-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-five-steps">
            <img src="images/vector/icon_5 step.png" width="30" height="30" class="five-step-icon">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="images/2.png">
                    <h4>Heading <br>Sub Heading</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p class="fw-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-five-steps">
            <img src="images/vector/icon_5 step.png" width="30" height="30" class="five-step-icon">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                   <img src="images/3.png">
                    <h4>Heading <br>Sub Heading</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                   <p class="fw-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="card-five-steps">
            <img src="images/vector/icon_5 step.png" width="30" height="30" class="five-step-icon">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="images/4.png">
                    <h4>Heading <br>Sub Heading</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p class="fw-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="card-five-steps">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="images/5.png">
                    <h4>Heading <br>Sub Heading</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p class="fw-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: set `display: flex` to `.card-five-steps` with `flex-direction: column` and change it to `flex-direction: row` in mobile view.

Comment: Thanks for your time...not working same result open in vertically

Comment: wait i am working on your code let see what will I get! 

Comment: I tried but you need to use javascript for some parts I am not able make it in pure CSS.